# Python SSL server SSLSocket SSLError when accessing via Safari and Firefox

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I'm writing a simple server for a class and there is a 'creative' component, so I want to add SSL to it. I'm trying to wrap the connection in an SSLSocket, but I get two different errors that I can't make out. The first happens with Safari when I try to wrap the socket, and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./junk.py", line 12, in <module>
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(connected_socket,certfile="cert.pem",keyfile="cert.pem",server_side=True,cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,suppress_ragged_eofs=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 372, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 296, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:503: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

When Safari tells the user that the certificate isn't valid (I created a self-signed cert via the command: `openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout cert.pem`), and then once I tell it that the cert is alright, the next time it goes through.

However, with Firefox, I get a completely different error, and it happens when I try to read what the client (Firefox) sent to the server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./junk.py", line 13, in <module>
    recieved = connstream.read() 
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 151, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1354: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

Below is the code that I used:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/python
  2 import socket
  3 import ssl
  4 
  5 serverPort = 22222
  6 serverSocket = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
  7 serverSocket.bind( ( '127.0.0.1', serverPort ) )
  8 serverSocket.listen( 10 )
  9 
 10 while True:
 11     connected_socket, from_addr = serverSocket.accept()
 12     connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(connected_socket,certfile="cert.pem",keyfile="cert.pem",server_side=True,cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,suppress_ragged_eofs=True)
 13     recieved = connstream.read()
 14     print recieved
 15     connstream.unwrap()
 16     connected_socket.close()
```

Can anyone help me understand:

1) What these errors mean

2) Why I'm getting them

3) How I can go about fixing these

(I've searched in just about every way I can think of)

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, I can't comment yet: this is not intended to be an answer.

Why always reinventing the wheel? I mean, if you want something python-based, why don't you use Tornado? BTW, you can see how they solve this problem there: http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpserver.html

People always seem to reinvent the wheel either for "educational purpose" or because existing solutions are too "bloated", "heavy", etc. (well, to sum up "*Not Invented Here*").
It's a shame because the same thing is done over and over, usually the wrong way.

Safari just don't honor the handshake, certainly because your cert is self signed.
Firefox just won't accept your cert because it is self-signed.
These errors are normal: the user has to accept the "trusted" connection in the browser. In the meanwhile, your server receives no answer or a rejection.

Look at Tornado to see how they handle that. But I really think you'd better study it, use it and contribute to it instead of creating a brand new, half-broken, http server.

Comment: While from a productivity standpoint, it would make sense to use some existing framework, from an "I know what is going on inside my computer, or on the internet" standpoint, you're a few simple lines of code away from being a white-hat script kiddie. Don't you think? Thank's for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Yes and no: you can *learn* from the code of the others. Tornado is simple to understand and opensource. You'll learn much more by looking at their code (and try to make yours work) than just getting the answer here. The difference is that in two years from now, you'll have reimplemented a lot of their features. This is just useless. If, however, you use their codebase as a start and implement new things, new features, you will still have to understand how the whole package works, how networks works, and you help the community. My two cents.

Comment: Good point -- and I agree completely. Wasting time to build what's already been built is silly. Maybe 'class' was ambiguous -- I'm writing this for a class for school (but the SSL is an extra bit I'm adding for fun, not required), so using Tornado isn't an option. All the same, I think implementing a small server over a few days just to see how it all works (i.e. learn by doing), and then moving on to contribute to something like Tornado is educational, and isn't harmful.

Comment: Most of the leading libraries we use today are re-inventions of something that existed before.  And they wouldn't exist without many failed attempts that lead to things nobody else used.  And for "wheels", I'm glad my car doesn't have a wooden circle that looks like it came off a Roman chariot.